# Windows update fails

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

### My PC is showing below updates since last 10-15 days but whenever I try to install, it fails. I have tried using Troubleshoot ==> Windows Update but still no luck. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Do you have enough storage space on the disk? For this error message, Microsoft recommends using the Repair Office feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried repairing Office? You can do this by going to the **control panel,** **uninstall a program,** **click Microsoft Office XXX** and clicking **change** at the top. I would suggest you do an "**Online repair**" after reboot and try to update.

If you still get the same error try to remove Office with all its updates **O15CTRRemove.diagcab**. You can get it from this link **https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2013-Office-2016-or-Office-365-from-a-Windows-computer-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8**

Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Reinstall Office updates**

1. Click the `Start` button, type `Windows Explorer` in the search box.
2. Click the `Windows Explorer` from the pop-up `Programs` menu
3. Navigate to `C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Office\data` path, find `opa12.dat` file and rename it to `opa12old.dat`.
4. When you restart Windows Office and open one file, it will prompt you to activate Windows Office, then activate it online.
5. Reinstall Windows Office updates and restart computer.

**Method 2: Reset Windows Update components**

If the issue is with the Windows update components, this method will resolve the issue by repairing all the components associated with it. Click on the link below and follow the article on the same.

[How do I reset Windows Update Components?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components)